# Не выводится обработанная строка. Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, вывод, ввод

Хочу ввести строку, убрать в ней все запятые, если встречаются и вывести уже обработанную строку, однако выводит ту же самую строку. Вот код:

```
.8086
.model small

.data
mybuf label byte
len db      254
newlen db      ?
mystr db      255 dup (36)
invite    db      'Enter string:$'
ctrl db 13,10,36

.stack 256 

.code

start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax 

 ;вывожу приглашение
 lea dx, invite
 mov ah, 9h
 int 21h

 ;ввод в буфер
 lea dx, mybuf
 mov ah, 0ah
 int 21h

 ;Enter
 lea dx, ctrl
 mov ah, 9h
 int 21h

 ;обработка строки(удаление ",")
 cld
 mov al, ','
 xor cl, cl
 mov bx, dx
 mov cx, [bx]+1   ;длина строки
 lea di, mystr    ;адрес строки
 REPNE SCASB
 JNZ  K20               ;Символ найден?
 DEC  DI                ;Да - уменьшить адрес.
 K20: 


 ;вывод строки
 lea dx, mystr
 mov ah, 9h
 int 21h

 ;ожидание нажатия клавиши
 mov ah, 8h
 int 21h

 mov ah, 4ch
 int 21h
end start
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут у меня больше вопросов, чем ответов.
mybuf label byte         ; ты объявил метку на следующие данные, зачем не знаю.

```
len db      254
newlen db      ?
mystr db      255 dup (36)

 ;ввод в буфер
 lea dx, mybuf  ; ввод считываешь по адресу метки в массив!!! len
 mov ah, 0ah
 int 21h
```

хотя в описание прерывания написано, что длина это 1 байт.

> Format of DOS input buffer:
>
> Offset  Size    Description     (Table 01344) 00h    BYTE    maximum
>   characters buffer can hold 01h    BYTE    (call) number of chars from
>   last input which may be recalled (ret) number of characters actually
>   read, excluding CR 02h  N BYTEs   actual characters read, including
>   the final carriage return

А вот следующие шаги ставят меня в ступор:

```
 ;Enter
 lea dx, ctrl
 mov ah, 9h
 int 21h
 mov bx, dx
 mov cx, [bx]+1   ;длина строки
```

Что оказывается в bx это загадка.

Да и цикл поиска запятой выглядит странно, во первых repne выполняется до первой запятой и как он ее найдет выйдет из программы.